# Add a sequence number for a field with jQuery clone

Tags: jquery

I have implemented jQuery clone as in the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/gqQnJ/5/

Now I want a sequence number (row no.) to be generated automatically each time a row is added (cloned).  Also, when a row is deleted (via DelRow button), I need the whole thing to be renumbered (so that there is no missing number in the sequence when we delete a row from middle).  The number has to show in the lineNo field.

Can anyone help me how I shall achieve this?

Also, I need to hide the 'DelRow' button from the first row only so that all rows are not deleted accidentally and atleast one row always exists (but this is the row that is being cloned and I need the button to show in all the other cloned rows).

Thanks for your time and help.

**Update:** Thanks Charles and Kei for your kind help.  I had to fuse both of your solutions to arrive at what I wanted.  The updated solution is posted below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sunalive/gqQnJ/13/

Comment: You need to show us what you've been working on, and where you're having a problem. Stackoverflow isn't here to code a concept for you.

Comment: But he has shown what he's been working on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gqQnJ/10/ But you assume the html isn't valid because the id lineNo is a duplicated id. So I think you should use another way to select or identify the input.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  That was really nifty.  I replaced ID with class in my code.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cSKEZ/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var autonumber = function() {
        $("tr.gridrow").each(function(i) {
            $(this).find("input[name='lineNo']").val(i + 1);
        });
    };
    autonumber();

    var emptyItems = $(".gridrow:first").clone();
    $(".addrow").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.gridcontainer').append(emptyItems.clone());
        autonumber();
    });

    $(".delrow").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('.gridrow').remove();
        autonumber();
    });
})
```

Watch out that you're not cloning tags with the same ID. You better use a class instead.